# Setting values in <input> tags after retrieving them from Database

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, redirect, dynamicobject

I have JSP page. In that page under HTML tags i have `<input>` tags. Now the values for these input tags are to be set, after they retrieved from the database using JDBC connectivity. Let's say i have a page `page1.jsp` in which i have a javascript code which contains a function inside which i am redirecting to the page where values are retrieved using database connection. Now when i execute query i get all the values in result set variable. I want these values to be send back again to `page1.jsp` so that i can use them to set as values for my  tags. I want to know how should i do this. should i store each value from result set variable to a session variable and use them later, or should i return rs variable back to page 1 and set values in `<input>` tag like `<%=rs.getInt("String")%>`. A guy suggest me to use Dynamic objects. I have heard about them, but never used them. What's the better way of doing this.

Comment: what do you mean by javascript "redirecting to the page where values are retrieved"? can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

First solutions is simple as you said you can store the values in session and retrieve them in page1.jsp. But i think you should go for Javascript Asyncronuos call generate your response in xml , Retrive it and populate into your page without refreshing your page.(Contents Updation). i.e

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get.asp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

More Information [Mastering Ajax](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro2/)

Comment: Session is not the right scope to store the values. You can use request scope for this.